# Exercício python ler arquivo Dat

Tags: python

Estou preso a um exercício que não consigo pensar em como resolver. O exercício consiste em um arquivo dat que contém uma linha para cada aluno de uma turma de estudantes. O nome de cada estudante está no início da cada linha e é seguido pelas suas notas e pede que escreva um programa que imprime o nome dos alunos que têm mais de seis notas.

notas_estudantes.dat

```
jose 10 15 20 30 40
pedro 23 16 19 22
suzana 8 22 17 14 32 17 24 21 2 9 11 17
gisela 12 28 21 45 26 10
joao 14 32 25 16 89
```

O que eu consegui fazer

```
arquivo = open('arquivos/notas_estudante.dat','r')
linha = arquivo.readlines()


for x in linha:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar em cada linha o método `split()` para obter as notas separadas e depois verificar quais alunos possuem mais de seis notas obtendo o tamanho da lista do índice 1 ao fim. Veja abaixo como ficaria:

```
with open("arquivos/notas_estudante.dat") as file:

    for line in file.readlines():
        data = line.split()

        if len(data[1:]) > 6:
            print(data[0])
```

Comment: Eu achei ótimo. Acho que é realmente isso que ele quer. Só um adendo ao amigo que perguntou, caso ele deseje também imprimir os que tem 6 notas e não somente os que têm mais de 6, ele altera a linha do IF.
`if len(data[1:]) >= 6:`